# How to resize UIViewController in UINavigationController automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UIViewController presenting in UINavigationController. In viewDidLoad, I added a UIView(self.loadingView) to UIViewController with below auto layout code:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.loadingView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.loadingView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.loadingView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.loadingView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

After running, I find that the self.loadingView is larger than the screen, and I can't see the bottom of self.loadingView, since we have an additional UINavigationbar above this view.

I can manually resize self.loadingView to fix this issue, but how to do it automatically. Specifically, I don't want to add `self.loadingView.frame.height-=44` in my project.

Comment: How do you want to display the loadingView?

Comment: show it below UINavigationbar

Comment: Instead of using `self.loadingView.frame.height-=44` with `[self.loadingView setNeedsLayout]; [self.loadingView layoutIfNeeded];`

Comment: could you answer my question with the detail implementation? where should I add the code you mentioned here.

Comment: Can you post your related cod about the additional UINavigationBar?

Comment: Thanks @Bannings for your followup, I just fixed this issue by setting autoresizingMask of self.loadingView

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout for the loadingView?  You need to disable Autoresizing Masks if you using AutoLayout